# Why periodically skip updating a parameter in MCMC?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

I'm looking at the MCMC code of a professor doing Metropolis-Hastings update of $(\theta, \alpha, \beta)$. $\theta$ and $\beta$ are matrices.

In his code,

1) He updates $\theta$ twice before updating $(\alpha, \beta)$ once.

2) He updates only a fraction of $\beta$ in each time he updates $\beta$.

What are these techniques for? Since I don't know the name of this techniques, search has been fruitless. Any reference is welcome.

```
for (i in 1:S) { # Start big MCMC loop
  theta <- update_theta(alpha, beta, data, theta)

  if (i % 2 ==0) { # Only update beta and theta after update theta twice
    alpha <- update_alpha(theta, beta, data)
    beta <- update_beta(theta, alpha, data)
}

update_beta(theta, alpha, data) {
  # Only consider 25% of the beta matrix for update
  which_beta_to_update <- ifelse( runif(length(beta)) <= .25, 1, 0 )
  deviation <- matrix(runif(length(beta), -1, 1) * which_beta_to_update, nrow = nrow(beta)
  betastar <- beta + deviation

  # After this, calculate MH acceptance ratio and update beta
}
```

Comment: When you say "fraction of beta" do you mean updating only parts of beta or do you mean updating all of beta but only sometimes? I don't know the details of MH MCMC, but my guess would be #1 is "thinning" in order to decrease autocorrelation, and #2 is rejection sampling. But I'm not sure.

Comment: whether reference to the code or perhaps write up of the algorithm we can't tell you whats going on

Comment: @bdeonovic I added the code.

Comment: i've never seen something like this, not even sure if this would result in valid MCMC

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This type of fine-tuned (Gibbs) MCMC is appropriate for cases when one conditional distribution is most "sticky" than other conditional distributions in the problem. For instance, updating only one [random] part of $\beta$ may be profitable when updating the whole vector results in high rejection rates or in very small moves. An early reference on mixing several MCMC steps is [Tierney (1994)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176325750). (Gareth Roberts and Jeff Rosenthal have also written several papers on comparing such mixtures of MCMC steps.)

However, updating the same parameter *twice* in a row, using the full conditional distribution given all others, is a waste of computational time since it means simulating *twice* from exactly the *same* distribution. The way the code is written, it seems to be the case:

`theta <- update_theta(alpha, beta, data)`

since the `update` function does not depend on the current value of `theta`. But when using a Metropolis-Hastings move using several iterations instead of one can make sense when the moves are of limited magnitude. Similarly, if the iterated calls to `update` modify only parts of the whole parameter `theta` and if those parts are chosen at random, this is a form of random block Gibbs sampling. And this is perfectly valid. Here is [an instance](http://www.hlt.utdallas.edu/~vgogate/papers/uai13-2.pdf) of such a strategy. And [an older one](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~zhaoxia/publications/paper3_Yuzx.pdf). (In an even [older paper with Christophe Andrieu](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Christian_Robert2/publication/2574717_Controlled_MCMC_for_Optimal_Sampling/links/5425c0a90cf26120b7afda48.pdf&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm1NOq41csvbjve6eXg-IZK1smaDDQ&nossl=1&oi=scholarr&ved=0ahUKEwiR8ori793QAhVEOhQKHWB3C2AQgAMIHCgAMAA), we looked at an adaptive choice for the size of the blocks, if not for the number of moves for given blocks. But this can be incorporated within an adaptive MCMC algorithm as well.)

> **Suggested Reading:** A most relevant paper that appeared [on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07056) a few days ago is
>   The *Recycling Gibbs Sampler for Efficient Learning* by Luca Martino,
>   Victor Elvira and Gustau Camps-Valls that I reviewed on [my blog
>   yesterday](http://wp.me/plc6Z-8mr).

Comment: 1. Could you give me a reference to read more about the "fine-tuned (Gibbs) MCMC" that updates a random part of $\beta$? 2. The `theta_update` in fact does depend on the current value of $\theta$ (my originally posted pseudo code is wrong). In my case, $\theta$ is a matrix of 0 and 1, and each `update_theta` considers flipping some of the cells. Given this, is there a name for the technique? 3. I omit the part where I calculate the acceptance ratio for $\beta$ and update accordingly.